# Checked radio button inside echo

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button

Trying to get my head around how to check radio buttons depending on the value? I will try my best to describe what I mean, It's confusing me. I have two radio buttons, A user can edit the value and it submits to the database. The data is pulled from Mysql using PHP.

I want to them to be checked depending on the value. Something like:

```
$checked = 'checked';  
$desktop = if($row["name"]=="desktop"){echo $checked;};
$mobile = if($row["name"]=="mobile"){echo $checked;};
```

Or along these lines, but how to do I achieve this? Here is my code:

```
echo "<li>
<div class='radio'>
<input type='radio' value='desktop' name = 'name[{$row['id']}]' id='desktop'>
<label for='href_desktop'>Desktop</label>
</div>
<div class='radio'>
<input type='radio' value='mobile' name = 'name[{$row['id']}]' id='mobile' >
<label for='href_mobile'>Mobile</label>
</div>
</div></li>"; }
```

Comment: are you using smarty?

Comment: No, but i will look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty solution to your problem:

```
$desktop_checked = $row['name'] == 'desktop' ? 'checked' : '';
$mobile_checked = $row['name'] == 'mobile' ? 'checked' : '';

echo "<li>
<div class='radio'>
<input type='radio' value='desktop' name = 'name[{$row['id']}]' id='desktop' $desktop_checked>
<label for='href_desktop'>Desktop</label>
</div>
<div class='radio'>
<input type='radio' value='mobile' name = 'name[{$row['id']}]' id='mobile' $mobile_checked>
<label for='href_mobile'>Mobile</label>
</div>
</div></li>"; }
```